# Returning from interact in expect script

Tags: tcl, expect

I am using DAOMATCH, an astronomy program to find matches between images and I am trying to semi-automate it with EXPECT.

The program asks for some input and, if it fails, he asks if I want to keep the transformation. This is why I want to semi-automate it: I want to give him input automatically but, when the "Write this transformation" question comes out, I want to have control on the program. For this purpose I have written (total beginner with TCL) this code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -D

set timeout 1

spawn "~/myDaophot/daophot4/daomatch"
expect "*Master*"
send "060326T034700403_4.als\r"
expect "*Output*"
send "060326T002448794_2_4.mch\r"
expect "*input*" {send "060326T034700403_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o "y\r" {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T034519602_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o "y\r" {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T034519602_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o "y\r" {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T002627552_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o "y\r" {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T003255953_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o "y\r" {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T003521749_2.als\r"}
#Question pops up here!!!
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o "y\r" {return}}
#-o needed, otherwise daomatch stops...
#\r needed otherwise, with "y" only, daomatch stops
expect "*input*" {send "060326T002539353_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o "y\r" {return}}
#other inputs.....
```

Now, this question does not pop up until where I marked it as a comment (simply because this is the first of the bad images). I give, by keyboard, y\r. DAOMATCH works until this command: I know this because, in the output, I find all the transformations, included this last one for which I answered "y\r".

However, at this point, this is what happens

```
 060326T003521749_2.als           -48    33   0.999   0.010  -0.010   0.999   0.95

         3    0.805    0.000    0.000    0.020    0.012
         2    2.000    2.000    0.400    0.500
 WT  0.804957092  <    2

                        Write this transformation? 

                    Next input file (default EXIT): zaamus@zaamuspc:~/Documenti/Fits/GCs/Omega_Cen$
```

So, the last expect is not executed. I have tried to change the timeout, to change return to inter_return but I still have not solved this.

I know there are some similar questions here but I cannot encapsulate expect in interact, since I have some 50-60 more inputs to give after the one which fails.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I found the solution: I had to add a -c to #!/usr/bin/expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -c

set timeout 1

spawn "~/myDaophot/daophot4/daomatch"

expect "*Master*" {send "060326T034700403_4.als\r"}
expect "*Output*" {send "060326T002448794_2_4.mch\r"}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T034700403_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T034519602_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T034519602_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T002627552_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T003255953_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T003521749_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T002539353_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T002627552_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T002715751_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T002539353_2.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
expect "*input*" {send "060326T034457403_4.als\r"}
expect "*transformation*" {interact -o y\r {return} n\r {return}}
```

One thing: I know that expect has a very strict syntax but interact only works the way I wrote there. If I try to add parentheses like this

```
interact -o {y\r {return} n\r {return}}
```

it will not work.